Change label name for same Lightning Web Component in Screen Flow
I am trying to use same LWC component in my flow for three different fields for validation purpose. It's showing First Name three times as shown in the picture. How do I show First Name, Last Name and Middle Name instead? Thanks!


This is happening because, you have set the "label" in the lightning-input tag to be static, with the value of "First Name".
To reuse a lightning web component (LWC) and name the label of the lightning-input dynamically, you have to make sure the label of the lightning-input accept a variable instead of a hard-coded text.
To achieve this, you can refer to the documentation here

Configure a Component for Flow Screens

Javascript
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  @api labelName;
}

HTML
<lightning-input label={labelName}>
</lightning-input>

XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Best Component Ever</masterLabel>
  <description>This is a demo component.</description>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
      <property name="labelName" label="Input Label Name" type="String" role="inputOnly" />
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

NOTE
Make sure the "name" in your XML's property tag, match the @api variable name in your JavaScript!

Credits: 
XML 
JavaScript
